# Xcode - Can't find library generated from Swift Package Manager

Tags: swift, xcode, swift-package-manager

I recently switched to SPM (from CocoaPods) and I have 2 targets for my project (one for release and one for sandbox).

Everything is ok for the release target (as it's the main target) but not for the sandbox target since I somehow should make these libs available to it.
The only way that I found that I can support 2 targets is to add the libs in Targets-> Frameworks, Libraries, and Embedded Content. It seems to work but the only issue is that one of my packages is not visible there ([Taplytics](https://github.com/taplytics/taplytics-ios-sdk))

Any ideas on where to find it and add it? Or a better way to support multiple targets with SPM?

PS.
The whole package is not visible in Targets-> Frameworks, Libraries, and Embedded Content

Comment: Are you building for macOS? If so, Taplytics is only supported via Catalyst.

Comment: No, I am building for iOS